# module for usb pen drive

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am making a module to do some basic stuff in my pen drive following the example [here](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/10/usb-drivers-in-linux-1/) . its stating that the usb storage(in my case pen drive) device uses usb-storage driver . I saw in hardware info that its usb_storage(which is same as usb-storage as when i do rmmod usb -storage it states that ERROR: Module usb_storage does not exist in /proc/modules) . I have done even lsmod with and without device its not showing any module name usb-storage.

My doubt is simple how to know which module controles which device and i know it could be unloaded by rmmod (module name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your kernel actually has usb-storage support this means the module is built in to the kernel and cannot be removed.

Try rebuilding your kernel after changing the usb-storage support to be built as a module, rather than directly into the kernel.

Comment: thank you for the answer but is there any way i can do it without again building my kernel....because it would take time....

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem removing the module if you are the Super user. Otherwise, change to super user then try to remove it. It can be done by `sudo su` command.

And for the list of modules being used, you can view the device log by `dmesg` and check out.